# Apache Camel - Exception is not catched

Tags: apache-camel

I read the corresponding documentation but I couldn't figure out why my Exception is not catched.

This is my route configuration:

```
  <route id="foo">
    <from uri="vm://.../>
    <doTry>
      <to uri="jetty:http://127.0.0.1:123/foo?restletMethod=PUT"/>
      <to uri="ejb:java:global/..?method=method1(${body}, ${headers})"/>
      <to uri="ejb:java:global/..?method=method2(${body}, ${headers})"/>
      <doCatch>
        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
        <transform>
           <simple> ${exception.message} </simple> 
        </transform>
        <to uri="smtp://... />
      </doCatch>
    </doTry>
  </route>
```

Now when the JettyClient is not reachable a `org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException` is thrown,
the route terminates and I receive an email. This is the desired behaviour.

But when `method1` throws an exception it is not catched, hence the route continues and 
I don't receive an email.

How can I make camel recognize and handle the exception in the second case too?

**Solution:** Make sure the exception isn't thrown inside a try-catch block -.-

Comment: Are you shure that method1 throws an exception? If you don't explicity catch an exception, camel will catch it in DefaultErrorHandler so route terminates too

Comment: Yes, it throws an exception.

Comment: Are you shure that code in method is invoked? because your `uri` is wrong, try this:
`<to uri="ejb:java:global/..?method=method1"/>`
I don't know why camel even starts with this.

Comment: Yes, the method is invoked. Just a typo in the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is stated in the documentation:
http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html

> Camel error handling is disabled
>
> When using doTry .. doCatch .. doFinally then the regular Camel Error
>   Handler does not apply. That means any onException or the likes does
>   not trigger. The reason is that doTry .. doCatch .. doFinally is in
>   fact its own error handler and that it aims to mimic and work like how
>   try/catch/finally works in Java.

You are probably better off to write it like this:

```
.doCatch(Exception.class)
        // and catch all other exceptions
        // they are handled by default (ie handled = true)
        .to("direct:error")
```

In direct:error you can specify what to do in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Is there any way to configure this in my above xml-structure?

Comment: By the way, what is the exception thrown in method 1?

Comment: Can you share the code for method1? Something else must be going on because I have done same procedure and the exception is caught. You don't have anything else there nested in a try catch in the method?

Comment: GNARF! That's it! There was a try-catch in the method .. -.- Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah that is a classic ;)